# Salesforce: Developers view

Tags: salesforce

We are in the process of deciding a route to take for a new CRM system. We've had Salesforce come in and give us their pitch and the developers have had a little play with it, made it do a few things we need etc...

It's hard for us to get a good idea of the pros and cons until we start to develop with it and if you start, you are tied in to a year contract for X number of users and it's pretty expensive as it is..

So, my question. Who has developed for sales force platform? how did you find the experience? would you recommend it as a good solution? Should we just continue with our ruby/rails/mongo systems?

Thanks!

Comment: Did your company finally choose to use salesforce? if yes, how did it result, it is painful as the answerer stated? One year after they still have same issues?

Comment: No, We stayed away from it and built our own system, its more focussed to the problems we have and none of the problems associated with using sales force :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The good news is the amount of customization you can do via configuration is amazing.  The out-of-box functionality is very strong and you get a pretty nice security model and reporting system included.

Having said that, when you do need to do custom development beyond what the configuration can support, the pain can start;

-APEX is the most frustrating (modern?) language I have ever worked with.

-Deployment/Migration can be slow and painful (some things cannot be migrated, e.g. Approval processes)

-APEX is a rather immature language missing much of the concepts of .net or java

-Debugging is messy (log actually gets truncated at a certain length, no stepping)

Having said all that, SalesForce.com is a very strong CRM - 90% of the custom work you'll want to do will be really smooth and fast, the remainder will be extremely painful.

Comment: One year after, do some of these cons have changed or are still the same?

Comment: Honestly, haven't been spending much time in lately.  From what I can see debugging tools have improved, but investment on the core language is lacking.